# Can I mix data types in buffers in OpenGL (C++)?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have an array of GLfloats that I use as positions and colors when I draw quads (so 4 floats per vertex). I'd like to add the ability to color my quads as well and figured I would pack the RGBA into a single GLuint and then send that to the GPU along with the positions.

So, can I somehow send 4 GLfloats and then 1 GLuint to the GPU?

Here's the relevant code:

```
void SpriteRenderer::Init()
{
    vertexBufferArrayInserts = 0;

    hasBegun = GL_FALSE;

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * MAX_VERTEX_BUFFER_SIZE, 0, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &elementBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLint) * MAX_ELEMENT_BUFFER_SIZE, 0, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //LOAD SHADER, CREATE AND USE PROGRAM
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayObject);
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);

    vertexShaderID = LoadShaderFromFile("Shader", GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fragmentShaderID = LoadShaderFromFile("Shader", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShaderID);

    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");

    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    shaderPosAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    glVertexAttribPointer(shaderPosAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 5, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shaderPosAttrib);

    shaderTexCoordAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "texCoord");
    glVertexAttribPointer(shaderTexCoordAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 5, (void*)(sizeof(GLfloat) * 2));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shaderTexCoordAttrib);

    shaderColorAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "Color");
    glVertexAttribPointer(shaderColorAttrib, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 5, (void*)(sizeof(GLfloat) * 4));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shaderColorAttrib);

    shaderProjMatAttrib = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projMat");

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void SpriteRenderer::Draw(Vector2<GLfloat> position, Rect clipRect)
{
    //TOP LEFT
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16] = position.X;
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 1] = position.Y;
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 2] = clipRect.GetLeftX() / 512.0f;
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 3] = clipRect.GetTopY() / 512.0f;
    colorBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 4] = PackColor(255, 255, 255, 255);

    //TOP RIGHT
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 4] = position.X + clipRect.GetWidth();
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 5] = position.Y;
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 6] = clipRect.GetRightX() / 512.0f;
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 7] = clipRect.GetTopY() / 512.0f;
    colorBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 4 + 1] = PackColor(255, 255, 255, 255);

    //BOTTOM RIGHT
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 8] = position.X + clipRect.GetWidth();
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 9] = position.Y + clipRect.GetHeight();
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 10] = clipRect.GetRightX() / 512.0f;
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 11] = clipRect.GetBottomY() / 512.0f;
    colorBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 4 + 2] = PackColor(255, 255, 255, 255);

    //BOTTOM LEFT
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 12] = position.X;
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 13] = position.Y + clipRect.GetHeight();
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 14] = clipRect.GetLeftX() / 512.0f;
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 15] = clipRect.GetBottomY() / 512.0f;
    colorBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 4 + 3] = PackColor(255, 255, 255, 255);

    //ELEMENT BUFFER
    elementBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 6] = vertexBufferArrayInserts * 4;
    elementBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 6 + 1] = vertexBufferArrayInserts * 4 + 1;
    elementBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 6 + 2] = vertexBufferArrayInserts * 4 + 2;
    elementBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 6 + 3] = vertexBufferArrayInserts * 4 + 2;
    elementBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 6 + 4] = vertexBufferArrayInserts * 4 + 3;
    elementBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 6 + 5] = vertexBufferArrayInserts * 4;

    vertexBufferArrayInserts++;

    if(vertexBufferArrayInserts == MAX_BUFFER_INSERTS)
        Draw();
}

void SpriteRenderer::Draw()
{
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLfloat) * vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16, vertexBufferArray);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16, sizeof(GLuint) * vertexBufferArrayInserts * 4, colorBufferArray);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLint) *  vertexBufferArrayInserts * 6, elementBufferArray);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vertexBufferArrayInserts * 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    vertexBufferArrayInserts = 0;
}

GLuint SpriteRenderer::PackColor(GLubyte r, GLubyte g, GLubyte b, GLubyte a) {
    GLint returnVal = (r << 24) + (g << 16) + (b << 8) + a;

    return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: He has the code to do it in his question. He enables the color attribute array, then uses `glVertexAttribPointer` to specify the location of the data. Then that data will be available in his vertex shader. Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I updated the original question

Comment: It could be helpful to see the rest of the code you tried (including shaders). For example, are you binding the buffer before calling `glVertexAttribPointer`? Are you filling the buffer correctly? Also, based on your call to `glVertexAttribPointer`, I assume you're structuring your array as {float, float, float, float, int, float float, float, float, int, ...}. But when using `glBufferSubData` you're only modifying the last fifth of the array? You may want to try just getting it working with 2 separate buffers first (which may be what you want in the first place).

Comment: I updated the post and just posted all the code (which I should've done first). Anyway I would like it to go float float float float int. But yes, my code isn't like that though... Would I have to use glVertexAttribPointer every time I call draw and set the offset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(shaderColorAttrib, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
  GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 5, (void*)(sizeof(GLfloat) * 4));
```

This will be unpacked as a single component.

Tell the GPU that you are sending four one-byte components (which adds up to a single 32-bit value):

```
glVertexAttribPointer(shaderColorAttrib, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
  GL_TRUE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 5, (void*)(sizeof(GLfloat) * 4));
```

Note that I set the normalized flag to true.  Do this if you're sending this to a `vec4` on the shader so that each component is convert to the `[0,1]` range you likely want it in.

Also, instead of doing the very error-prone math with `sizeof(float)`, consider making a struct and using the size of that struct and `offsetof` to generate your stride and vertex offsets:

```
struct vertex {
   float4 position;
   ubyte4 color;
};

glVertexAttribPointer(shaderColorAttrib, 4, GL_FLOAT,
  GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), offsetof(vertex, position));
glVertexAttribPointer(shaderColorAttrib, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
  GL_TRUE, sizeof(vertex), offsetof(vertex, color));
```

This becomes way more critical once you start mixing data types.  Just be aware of struct padding; using `offsetof` will ensure things work, but you don't want to be wasteful with your buffer object space.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);` is called, and then `glBufferSubData` is called without binding the buffer again. Isn't this a problem? I'm a bit new to OpenGL as well so I'm asking this for my own understanding :P

Comment: Yes, I unbind the buffer there but I bind it before trying to put data into it.

How would I send the data to the GPU then? Can I do it using one `glBufferSubData`?

Comment: And this is the problem with big code dumps.  Lots of red herrings, incomplete code paths, and honestly there was no way I was going to look as closely at it as Taylor apparently did. :)

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer. The problem wasn't the `glVertexAttribPointer`. It was that I needed to put everything in a struct and then send an array of that struct to the GPU! Thanks for the help!